# How to access other/third-party app remote notifications - iOS 8?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8.2

Recently Google has launched new [Android Wear](https://itunes.apple.com/app/androidwear/id986496028) app which support iOS 8.2+ & it is able to access/read *other* app notifications, it also shows notification on *wear watch* as soon as they are received (*as shown in below image also it is working with real watch/iPhone as tested by us*).
I have gone through [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) background execution guide but no luck :(

> So How can I access remote/push notification of third party app like
>   *WhatsApp/Hangout* in my app using Swift?

[image]

Comment: I imagine that the watch receives the notification using ANCS and then sends the notification back to the iOS app over Bluetooth.  The app can't read notifications directly

Comment: ok I just read about ANCS & GATT so now I also think they might be using that only thanks. @Paulw11